# how to correctly use |> operator?

Tags: functional-programming, elm

i get an error when i try use the `|>` operator in elm

```
kl : List Float
kl =
    List.map toFloat (List.range 1 10)
```

```
kll : Float
kll =
    let
        half x =
            x / 2
    in
    List.sum (List.map half (List.map toFloat (List.range 1 10)))
```

The code below i use the `|>` and get an error:

```
klpipe : List Float
klpipe =
    1 10 |> List.range |> toFloat |> List.map
```

Comment: Please include more details such as what error you got. It is also unclear what is your question specifically, where did you get stuck. Do you understand the concept of `|>`? Like could you come up with an example where it worked for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`|>` can only be used to apply a single argument on the left side to a function on the right side. Here's a few examples to give you an intuition of how it works:

```
x |> f == f x
y |> f x == f x y
f x |> g == g (f x)
```

You *can* apply multiple arguments to a single function using `|>`, but you'll have to do it one at a time in revers order and use parentheses to go against its natural associativity:

```
10 |> (1 |> List.range) |> (toFloat |> List.map)
```

Here the parenthesized expressions both evaluate to functions that "fit" on the right side of the pipe. Without parentheses, `1 |> 10 |> List.range` would be equivalent to `List.range (10 1).

I don't find this very readable however, and would instead use the pipe operator much more sparingly:

```
List.range 1 10 |> List.map toFloat
```

Just because you can make it look like a nail doesn't mean you should use a hammer on it.

Comment: what about the second expression kll??

Comment: Also, this appears to be a homework assignment so I'm a bit reluctant to just give you the answer. You should be able to derive a solution yourself from the explanation in my answer. Although if you have a specific problem with your code, like an error message you don't understand, feel free to ask about that.

Comment: Thanks thats fine, im not looking for the answer but an explanation for it. Thanks

Comment: i managed to get this  ```((1 |> 10 |> List.range) |> toFloat |> List.map) (|>half |> List.map))|> List.sum```

Comment: However i receive this error  ```This function cannot handle the argument sent through the (|>) pipe:

     (1 |> 10 |> List.range) |> toFloat |> List.map |> half |> List.map |> List.sum
The argument is:

    Int -> List Int

But (|>) is piping it to a function that expects:

    Int (literate-elm:compile)  ```