# How to use |> operator with a function which expects two parameters?

Tags: functional-programming, elm, purely-functional

```
kll : Float
kll =
    let
        half x =
            x / 2
    in
    List.sum (List.map half (List.map toFloat (List.range 1 10)))
```

converting using `|>`

can you also explain how to use the `|>` correctly with some examples cant find any online?
Thanks
This is my code:

```
kll : List Float
kll =
    let
        half x =
            x / 2
    in
    ((1 |> 1 |> List.range) |> toFloat |> List.map) (|>half |> List.map))|> List.sum
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to correctly use |> operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64480001/how-to-correctly-use-operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|>` doesn't work with 2-parameter functions. It only feeds into functions that take one parameter.

Use currying to supply leading parameters. I think what you want is this:

```
List.range 1 10 |> List.map toFloat |> List.map half |> List.sum
```

Or more simply:

```
List.range 1 10 |> List.map (\x -> toFloat x / 2) |> List.sum
```